# ProGuard obfuscation variable naming, how to avoid local and param prefixes?

Tags: java, spring, proguard

I am trying to obfuscate a spring web application using ProGuard. I want to keep class and method names, especially the ones used as spring beans.

But ProGuard renames local variables to `local[class name]`, for example if I have a `User` object it renames the local variable to `localUser`. It also renames method parameters to `param[Class name]`, for example if I have a User parameter the variable name in obfuscated method becomes `paramUser`. So the obfuscated code becomes pretty readable.

I want to prevent ProGuard using local and param prefixes and class names. For example I want it to use `x1` instead of `localUser`. I checked configuration options but I could not find how to do that.

Comment: I use ProGuard heavily; but when I have inspected obfuscated classes all obfuscated names are systematically renamed to 1 or 2 letters (regardless of their context).  I have not seen evidence of the kind of naming scheme you are describing, which leads me to think that perhaps their is some config option you are specifying which is causing it.

Comment: I am keeping  some of the class and method names. That's why some of the class and method names are not converted to a,b etc

Comment: have you managed to fully obfuscate your application , because i'm facing a spring configuration nightmare for my webApplication ..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html) > Unexpected observations after processing > Variable names not being obfuscated

> If the names of the local variables and parameters in your obfuscated
>   code don't look obfuscated, because they suspiciously resemble the
>   names of their types, it's probably because the decompiler that you
>   are using is coming up with those names. ProGuard's obfuscation step
>   does remove the original names entirely, unless you explicitly keep
>   the LocalVariableTable or LocalVariableTypeTable attributes.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `x1` isn't giving away any more information than `paramUser`, given that the viewed code would be:

```
public void foo(User x1)
{
    ...
}
```

Unless your methods are really long, it wouldn't be hard for anyone reading the method to remember that it's a parameter of type `User`, which is all that `paramUser` is saying. Yes, there's a bit of a difference in readability but I wouldn't say it's worth worrying about, personally - if someone's investing enough time to decompile your code to start with, a very small difference like that would be unlikely to deter them. If the class names were obfuscated as well, that makes a bigger difference IMO.

Comment: You are right but I am just trying to make it a little bit harder to read. Do you know about better obfuscation solution for Spring beans? I mean obfuscating class and method names without getting into a spring application configuration nightmare.

Comment: @Serkan: I don't know of a better solution, but if your Spring configuration is in XML I would expect it to be feasible to automatically modify that to use the new obfuscated names provided by Proguard.

Comment: proguard obfuscates the getters and setters in a way that doesn't respect the java bean convention which leads to a reflection breakdown .  excluding every spring bean from obfuscation is kind of stupid , especialy when a lot of layers make extensive use of spring injections

Answer (score 0):

The naming scheme, you are describing, looks like the names regenerated by JD when the LocalVariableTable has been skipped by a Java compiler (see javac -g:var). For me, this is not a bug of ProGuard.

To make more efficient the obfuscation of your applications,

- try to replace "protected" by "private" each time that is possible : ProGuard will replace the class, method and field names by short names,
- try to use anonymous classes in your code,
- and try to split your algoritms in a large number of classes to complexify the understanding of the execution flows.